# How to configure maven hbm2hbmxml and hbm2java to run one after the other in mvn clean install

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I need to be able to call mvn clean install and have maven call hibernate3:hbm2hbmxml to generate the mapping files from a database and after than call hbm2java to get the Java files and then have maven compile those newly created Java files. 
Has anyone done this before?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer stating how to "manually" (through maven) copy the files to desired location

Answer (score 14):

If you want to have your model java files (obtained by reveng) compiled, you don't need to run hbm2hbmxml.

plugin configuration:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2java</name>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                    <revengfile>/src/main/resources/reveng/model.reveng.xml</revengfile>
                    <propertyfile>/src/main/resources/META-INF/hibernate.properties</propertyfile>
                    <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                    <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1_3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>             
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

hibernate.properties :

```xml
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB
hibernate.connection.username = yourUsrName
hibernate.connection.password= yourPwd
hibernate.default_schema = YOUR_DB
```

model.reveng.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter match-name=".*" package="your.package.here" />
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

you fire this with:

```xml
mvn clean hibernate3:hbm2java compile
```

if you want it to be fired just with:

```xml
mvn clean compile
```

add the "executions" tag in your plugin definition

```xml
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals><goal>hbm2java</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Answer (score 6):

Neither of the two answers worked for me out of the box. After a bit of research, I was able to generate POJOs from a database. Hope this fast tracks someone.

Simply generate the java files - no mapping files generated.

Define your database connection in src/test/resources/reveng/hibernate.cfg.xml. Using the test branch so these files are not copied into the distributable artifact.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="pmSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <!-- Note that we are pointing directly at the catalog so we can use 
             unqualified table names -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.domain.com:1521:catalog</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">login</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PM</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Create a list of tables you want to import. Again in the test branch: src/test/resources/reveng/model.reveng.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" 
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <!-- This assumes your database connection is pointing to the proper catalog -->
  <!-- To get all tables in the named schema, use the following 
       <schema-selection match-schema="PM" />
  -->
  <!--  to get only the named tables -->
  <schema-selection match-schema="PM" match-table="PM_PROPERTY"/>
  <schema-selection match-schema="PM" match-table="PM_APPLICATION"/>
  <schema-selection match-schema="PM" match-table="PM_PROPERTY_TYPE"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Add the hibernate3 maven plugin to your pom

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <components>
          <component>
            <name>hbm2java</name>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/java/com/me/examples/pm/data</outputDirectory>
            <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
          </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
          <!-- Storing the reveng files in the test branch means we are not 
               deploying connection information-->
          <revengfile>src/test/resources/reveng/model.reveng.xml</revengfile>
          <configurationfile>src/test/resources/reveng/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
          <jdk5>true</jdk5>
          <ejb3>true</ejb3>
        </componentProperties>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>classes12</artifactId>
          <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
          <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Run maven

```xml
mvn hibernate3:hbm2java
```

Answer (score 1):

[Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package
```

> If this were to be executed, the clean phase will be executed first (meaning it will run all preceeding phases of the clean lifecycle, plus the clean phase itself), and then the dependency:copy-dependencies goal, before finally executing the package phase (and all its preceeding build phases of the default lifecycle).

So, *perhaps*:

```
mvn clean hibernate3:hbm2hbmxml hibernate3:hbm2java package
```

That said, I'd recommend against perpetually generating classes. This makes you very inflexible.

After your comment, it seems like an "unwise" behaviour from the hibernate plugin. You can bypass that by "manually" copying the required files to the desired directory, using the [Maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Comment: Bozho, this is not exactly how I understood the question (which isn't trivial at all, the wanted workflow involves really tricky configuration of the hibernate3 plugin). But maybe I missed something.

Comment: I also wasn't sure I'm getting everything, but at least he should give it a try this way, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I'm looking for is to be able to make those goals part of my continuous integration process. I managed to make hbm2hbmxml work but places the *.hbm.xml files under ./target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/mypackage. When I run hbm2java I get a failure saying "mypackage/Domain.hbm.xml not found". Shouldn't the plugin know where to find those files?
I made that run by adding the <outputdirectory> entry and hbm2java generates the source code but again, it places the Java files under the target folder and when I compile it doesn't compile those files. 
Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Working Example for **hibernate3-maven-plugin** version **3.0** & **hbm2java**

```
<profile>
    <id>hbm2java</id>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <hibernatetool>
            <classpath>
                <path location="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
            </classpath>
            <jdbcconfiguration propertyfile="${basedir}/helper/hibernate.properties" revengfile="${basedir}/helper/hibernate-reverse-engineering.xml"
                reversestrategy="de.hibernate.ExampleStrategy" />
            <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true" destdir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}" />
            </hibernatetool>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- must be compile or higher to find ExampleStrategy class in same project -->
            <phase>compile</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following config works for me. (sample is with Derby database and 1 table)

mvn clean package does it all.


the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>hbm2hbmxml</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>hbm2hbmxml</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <components>
                <component>
                    <name>hbm2hbmxml</name>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                </component>
            </components>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>hbm2java</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>hbm2java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <components>
                <component>
                    <name>hbm2java</name>
                    <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                </component>
            </components>
            <componentProperties>
                <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                <configurationfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
                </configurationfile>
            </componentProperties>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/demo</property>
    <property name="connection.username">app</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="Tag.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Hibernate 2 plugin in your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-mapping-files</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>

                 <goals>
                    <goal>hbm2hbmxml</goal>
                    <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
                    <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                </goals>
...
```

Then in model Reveng put this.

```
<!-- Primary Tables -->
 <schema-selection match-schema="TEST_SCHEMA" match-table="TEST_TABLE" />
```

Then just build your project in maven using `clean install` and the model classes will be generated automatically from the database.