# Is it possible to generate Annotated Java classes using Mojo's Hibernate plug-in?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

I know that hbm2hbmxml generates the necessary mapping files (*.hbm.xml) from a given datasource. You can then use hbm2java which will use those hbm.xml files as an input and will output Java classes. Is there a way of generating Java Annotated classes from the datasource without having to rely on the hbm.xml files?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-use-hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-an-existing-database/

Answer (score 0):

You can use hbm2java for reverse engineering. There are the hibernate tools docs:

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#refeng_codegen

With the reveng file configuration you can instruct hibernate tools to create the java model from the database.

And there is one example from another SO question:

[How to configure maven hbm2hbmxml and hbm2java to run one after the other in mvn clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083727/how-to-configure-maven-hbm2hbmxml-and-hbm2java-to-run-one-after-the-other-in-mvn)