# Maven Rever Engine with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data

I follow this example to create hibernate hbm2java and it is successfully creating domains

[How to configure maven hbm2hbmxml and hbm2java to run one after the other in mvn clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083727/how-to-configure-maven-hbm2hbmxml-and-hbm2java-to-run-one-after-the-other-in-mvn)

how can i do with DAO's also with Spring Data JPA Repositories

can any one explain to me or which plugin i want to use

Thanks and Regards
pradeep

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you experiencing some problems? The [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) is quite comprehensive.

Comment: i need jpa auto-genration maven plugin