# Is there a way to generate jpa/hibernate model classes from database without using JBoss hibernate tools ?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I've restricted access to the eclipse market place and a network with terrible connectivity issues , therefore i wont be able to download Jboss tools which is like more than 300MB .

Is there a way to generate jpa/hibernate model classes from database without using JBoss hibernate tools ?

Comment: Eclipse Dali plugin ? "Dali Java Persistence Tools" IIRC. That would generate JPA, hence usable on any provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible to generate hibernate/jpa specific model classes from you database using hibernate maven plugin. Only thing is your project should be maven project.

Please refer below links:

In the below link plz check the first answer provided by John citizen.
[https://developer.jboss.org/message/801478?_sscc=t#801478][1]

below link for any trouble shooting.

[How to configure maven hbm2hbmxml and hbm2java to run one after the other in mvn clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083727/how-to-configure-maven-hbm2hbmxml-and-hbm2java-to-run-one-after-the-other-in-mvn)

Comment: I was able to generate the model classes , dao's didn't work though.