# Is there a Django's inspectdb equivalent for Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inspectdb

I've used Django's inspectdb command in the past, which gives you models from an existing database.

I've searched and I found some GUI tools like jboss tools, but I think It's not what I'm looking for cause It's too heavy.

Is there something equivalent for hibernate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083727/how-to-configure-maven-hbm2hbmxml-and-hbm2java-to-run-one-after-the-other-in-mvn

Comment: after some researches, I found [this](https://github.com/Infeligo/modelgen) repo. I think this place might be a great starting point for the others too.